# How to make a text field fit in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

Does anyone know how to make the size of a text field shrink in Dynamics CRM 2011? 
I tried to find a solution online but it seems impossible.

Now, there is a setting that allows me to fit a text box to size of `document.window` but it's too big.

I'd like to make it based on the length of a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the form editor will use the maximum amount of space available for the text field, and there is no "CRM supported" methodology for specifying the exact size.  You could add spacers on the form to take up some of the usable space, but that would have to be done by hand, not based on the text size of the field.

The unsupported method would be finding the text box in the DOM and editing it via javascript/Jquery during the onload.

Comment: and what about an angle that allow users to expand a text box, is it possible to do there? I've not found the solution for this yet. What do you say?

Comment: @Leo There is nothing "built in" to dynamically control the size of the text box.  CRM isn't designed to be the prettiest thing, it's designed to be a rapid application development platform.  You can go the route Konrad suggests or use silverlight to make the UI do exactly what you want.  But you will loose the use of the form editor.

Answer (score 1):

If the settings of forms and controls are not enough, you might consider creating your own web resource containing HTML document where you have full control. Then you can stuff it in using an IFRAME. But it's usually a lot of work.